# Configuring LDAP server in WSO2 API1.7

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to configure LDAP server in the WSO2 api manager so that I would be able to login with my LDAP username.
I made the configurations as per the docs available and I do not get any issues during server startup but when I try to login with the username, it fails to log me in and gives the error as below in the console :

```
 WARN - CarbonAuthenticationUtil Failed Administrator login attempt 'sm38553[-1234]' at [2016-03-31 15:51:42,564+0530] from IP address 10.42.47.196
[2016-03-31 15:51:42,566]  WARN - AuthenticationHandler Illegal access attempt at [2016-03-31 15:51:42,0566] from IP address 10.42.47.196 while trying to authenticate access to service LoggedUserInfoAdmin
[2016-03-31 15:51:42,567] ERROR - AUDIT_LOG Illegal access attempt at [2016-03-31 15:51:42,0566] from IP address 10.42.47.196 while trying to authenticate access to service LoggedUserInfoAdmin
```

Comment: Were you able to login using super tenant admin user?

Comment: Yes,admin user still works for me.Currently I am trying to configure the api manager to authenticate me while login and therefore I am setting up the LDAP server.I am making the changes in the usr-mgt.xml file and trying to use the ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.

Comment: Have you tried to login Management Console or publisher or store? Your users should have appropriate permission to login

Comment: I have made the following changes in the usr-mgt.xml file `<AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
                <AdminUser>
    <UserName>sm38553</UserName>
    <Password>****</Password>
                </AdminUser>`  which means now I should be able to login the management console with the username as provided here.

Comment: Yes. I will add this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use different username for super admin, you have to change it in user-mgt.xml file

```
<Configuration>
     <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
     <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
     <AdminUser>
       <UserName>abimaran</UserName>
       <Password>abimaran</Password>
     </AdminUser>
     <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
     <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Yes, I made these changes and now trying to login with the username and password as mentioned in the usr-mgt.xml file but I am getting error `ERROR - AUDIT_LOG Illegal access attempt while trying to authenticate access to service LoggedUserInfoAdmin`

Comment: This user don't have any impact on whether you are using LDAP or JDBC. we have to configure in the user-mgt.xml file. I have tested this and works fine.